# play framework (java) list-modules got Not a valid command

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm starting with play framework and got stuck when studying modules.
Both commands **modules** and **list-modules** throws the same error message (see below). Maybe my version needs to be upgraded, If so, please explain me how.
Any help will be welcome.

**#Error**

```
    [Cesars-Computer: email-server-play] $ play modules
    [info] Loading project definition from /path-to-play-app/email-server-play/project
    [info] Set current project to email-server-play (in build file:/path-to-play-app/email-server-play/)
    [error] Not a valid command: modules
    [error] Expected '/'
    [error] Expected ':'
    [error] Not a valid key: modules (similar: ivy-module, module-name, module-settings)
    [error] modules
    [error]        ^

    [Cesars-Computer: email-server-play] $ play list-modules
    [info] Loading project definition from /path-to-play-app/email-server-play/project
    [info] Set current project to email-server-play (in build file:/path-to-play-app/email-server-play/)
    [error] Not a valid command: list-modules
    [error] Expected '/'
    [error] Expected ':'
    [error] Not a valid key: list-modules (similar: ivy-module, classifiers-module)
    [error] list-modules
    [error]             ^
```

Play console running version is 2.1.1., but strangely show version 1.0-SNAPSHOT, when I call version command.

**# Some additional info**

```
    [Cesars-Computer: email-server-play] $ play
    [info] Loading project definition from /path-to-play-app/email-server-play/project
    [info] Set current project to email-server-play (in build file:/path-to-play-app/email-server-play/)
           _            _
     _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
    | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
    |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
    |_|            |__/

    play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_11 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

    > Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
    > Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.


    [email-server-play] $ version
    [info] 1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `projects` to list all the modules.

To work on a given module, run

```
project my_module
```

Here's a link to the documentation:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTSubProjects

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. I didn't understand: modules and list-modules commands aren't suppose to work this way?  I'm working on a single project, I'm following the book Play Framework Cookbook, and at this part of it, it tells me to look for installed modules, apparently those commands are suppose to work within project directory. Please can u tell me if they work for u?

Comment: Are you using Play 1.x Cookbook?  It seems that is old syntax: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/modules

Comment: Strage because, also netbeansify got the same message, although the link u showed is a strong indication, I would like to know: netbeansify runs in your machine? Regardless, I'll try another book, do you recommend anyone, or another learning method? Thanks again!

Comment: I also had the Play Framework Cookbook.  Under section `Downloading and installing the Play framework`, it says `at the time of writing this recpe play 1.2 was the latest stable version`.  The book I recommend is `Manning: Play for Java`.  You may find this book from Play's official website: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Home.

Comment: I used Eclipse.  Play 1.x uses command `play eclipsify`, and the new Play 2.x uses command `play eclipse`.

Comment: Thanks very much, You were right, It was a lack of attention, the commands really changed on the new version. Thanks for book recommendation. Nice!